Steps to Retrieve GET_V2_SETTLEMENT_REPORT_DATA_FLAT_FILE_V2 through Amazon SP-API
I am trying to retrieve GET_V2_SETTLEMENT_REPORT_DATA_FLAT_FILE_V2 report via SP-API and I understand that I cannot use create report method here. I can only retrieve the reports made available by amazon already. Could anyone help me out here? A short summary of steps involved would also be great.
I used get_report for this but I am not sure how to get the report ID for this request

Settlements reports, like GET_V2_SETTLEMENT_REPORT_DATA_FLAT_FILE_V2, cannot be requested, but they are automatically generated on a scheduled basis by Amazon.
In order to retrieve a report like this, you have to perform the following steps:

call the getReports API, passing in GET_V2_SETTLEMENT_REPORT_DATA_FLAT_FILE_V2 as reportTypes parameter and setting a value at least for marketplaceIds. You can also set values for these parameters: createdSince (if you want to specify a creation date), processingStatuses (e.g. to DONE if you want to get only those who are really ready to be downloaded) and pageSize if the default 10 is not ok for you  (max 100).
for each report contained in the response, you can just get the reportDocumentId parameter
use the reportDocumentId parameter to perform a getReportDocument API call

